# set font from assets folder for SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, fonts, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to set  font from assets folder for the below code

```
int[] listeitems = new int[] { R.id.title };
        Typeface childFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");

        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item,
                null,
                new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                // android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,

                }, listeitems, 0);


        try {
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

How can we set font for  SimpleCursorAdapter  for above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Create FontStyle class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class FontStyle {
    public static Typeface OswaldRegular(Context context) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Oswald-Regular.ttf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

**Set the below code for setting your font style to your activity:**

```
TextView txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
txtHeader.setTypeface(FontStyle.OswaldRegular(MainActivity.this));
```

Answer (score 0):

into  SimpleCursorAdapter class 
       Typeface childFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
textfield.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);

Answer (score 0):

please see this

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binding = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        boolean SetViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          TextView tv1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          TextView tv2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
          TextView tv3=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
          //Setting typeface  here
          return true;
        }
    });
adapter.setViewBinder(binding);
```